Proving $\phi(t)=e^{−|t|^{\alpha}}$ is not a characteristic function for α>2.
Problem: Show that the function $\phi(t) = e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}$ is NOT a characteristic function.
I have calculated the first two derivatives:
$$\phi'(t) = \frac{-\alpha |t|^{\alpha}e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}}{t}$$
$$\phi''(t)= \frac{[-\alpha (-\alpha |t|^{\alpha-1}e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}+\frac{t}{|t|}\alpha|t|^{\alpha-1}e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}|t|^{\alpha})]t+\alpha|t|^{\alpha}e^{-|t|^{\alpha}}}{t^2}$$
Neither of these are defined at zero so I am not able to conclude that we have a finite expectation to derive a contradiction by the sign of the variance or uniform continuity as I might expect.
What other strategies can I use to disprove that this is a characteristic function?

Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3592118/27978
